# "Позвольте нам продолжить обсуждение в чате"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, чат

Когда комментариев становится слишком много, система предлагает создать комнату для обсуждения в чате. Тот, кто в итоге эту комнату создаёт, оставляет комментарий со следующим текстом:

> Позвольте нам **продолжить обсуждение в чате**.

Насколько я помню английский SO, там это звучит так:

> Let us **continue this discussion in chat**.

Перевод на русский очевидно машинный и некорректный.

---

Поскольку вариантов много, добавляю оглавление, в алфавитном порядке:

- [Давайте перенесём обсуждение в чат.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1061/181472)
- [Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1058/181472)
- [Давайте продолжим это обсуждение в чате.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1023/181472)
- [Позвольте нам продолжить обсуждение в чате.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1022/181472)
- [Предлагаю вам продолжить обсуждение в чате.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1059/181472)
- [Предлагаю нам продолжить обсуждение в чате.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1024/181472)
- [Предлагаю нам с вами продолжить обсуждение в чате.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1060/181472)

Comment: Я пока не слишком знаком с процессом исправления перевода, поэтому свой вариант пишу здесь: "Давайте **продолжим это обсуждение в чате**". Всё-таки это уже не часть проблемы, а кусочек решения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте предлагаемый вариант перевода в виде ответа к вопросу.

Comment: @D-side: Вот как мы обсуждаем переводы: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494/181472

Comment: Закинул обсуждение на сайт по русскому языку. http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/9436/5582

Comment: Всё-таки суток недостаточно для предложения и выбора вариантов перевода. Снял галочку в связи с внезапным притоком вариантов и доводов.

Comment: @D-side: Верное решение ) Мы тут можем переводы обсуждать и по три недели: [Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/866/181472), [Перевести имя участника Community](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/851/181472)

Comment: *"очевидно машинный и некорректный"* -- я не робот (честно) и мне лично нравится *"Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате"* вариант, но я не вижу *такой уж большой* проблемы и с исходным вариантом: *"Позвольте нам продолжить обсуждение в чате"*

Comment: Внес победивший вариант в Transifex в виде задачи. Теперь ждем подтверждения.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Как вариант D-side, но без местоимения. Мне этот вариант кажется наиболее лаконичным и дружелюбным.

[Предложено участником @Alex_ander на Russian.SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/9437/5582)

Answer (score 2):

Заменить на:

> Давайте продолжим это обсуждение в чате.

Comment: Как насчет варианта без местоимения? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1058/181472

Answer (score 2):

Еще более дружелюбная форма:

> Предлагаю нам с вами продолжить обсуждение в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

[Предложено участником @Alex_ander на Russian.SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9436/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC/9438#comment20745_9437)

Answer (score 2):

> Давайте перенесём обсуждение в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Прежнее дружелюбие + акцент на устройство движка сайта, который предоставляет возможность скопировать все комментарии.

Comment: Не знаю, стоило ли изначально брать «е» вместо «ё», но менять «ё» на «е» смысла точно нет.

Comment: @D-side: не понял вас. В этом варианте я сразу выбрал ё.

Comment: ...и я не вижу смысла ставить этот выбор под сомнение, раз он уже сделан. К тому же, на мой взгляд, в «“е” в роли “ё”» заложена некоторая неоднозначность, а неоднозначность это плохо.

Comment: @D-side: а, теперь понял.

Answer (score 1):

Исходная строка звучит так

> Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Строка переведена корректно, то есть следует оставить

> Позвольте нам продолжить обсуждение в чате.

Comment: Согласен, что корректно. Но на мой вкус, немного слишком официально.

Comment: На мой взгляд, это "пословный" (характерный для машинного) перевод с потерей части смысла. Это больше звучит, как "разрешите", нежели как "предлагаю".

Comment: @D-side: действительно, есть оттенок смысла «разрешите».

Answer (score 1):

Акцент на то, что я тоже приду в чат, чтобы продолжить обсуждение.

> Предлагаю нам продолжить обсуждение в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: `Нам` или `вам`?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: тонкий момент. Я исходил из того, что странно предлагать что-то себе, поэтому я предлагаю собеседнику, т.е. «вам». С другой стороны, «нам» подчеркивает, что я тоже буду общаться в чате, а не только собеседника туда отправляю.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: затрудняюсь сделать выбор. Может, филологам закинуть вопрос?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ...или без местоимения вовсе?

Comment: Пояснение к последнему варианту повеселило =) Распилите ответ на отдельные варианты, пожалуйста.

Comment: @D-side: распилил.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант, предложенный первым, менее дружелюбный. Можно понять как "предлагаю вам выпить яду, убиться об стену и пойти ...".

> Предлагаю вам продолжить обсуждение в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).